# Double Integral over the region bounded by the lines

Tags: integration

i'm wondering how to write double integral based on a given region 
[image]
i just want explaination about how to use D region to express the double integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

For $\;0<x<1\;,\;\;x^2\le\sqrt x\;$ , so I'd try

$$\int_0^1\int_{x^2}^{\sqrt x}f(x,y) dy dx$$

Comment: if i understand correctly your hint, then in my example, sqrt(x) < y < x^2, and sqrt(y) < x < y^2

Comment: $\int_{\sqrt x}^{x^2}\int_{y^2}^{\sqrt y}{(x^2+y)}dxdy$, is this correct?

Comment: @corfto no no, very wrong. If you did that your double integral would result in a function of 2 variables. As $y\in(x^2,\sqrt x)$ then $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: @corfto You **already** have the double integral limits...Now you must do the actual integration. But first it should be clear to you why those are the correct limits...